# Spring JdbcTemplate resultset empty first time

Tags: jdbctemplate

Put simply, the problem is that the result set is empty the first time around I call the JdbcTemplate and query the database.

When I access the DAO methods for the second time, I get the expected results. Here is more information about how the classes are setup:

I have a data access object that extends a parent data access object. Parent dao class simply injects the data-sources into the constructors of JdbcTemplate:

```
public class BaseDao
{
    private JdbcTemplate usrJdbcTemplate;

    public void setUsrDataSource(DataSource usrDataSource)
    {
        this.usrJdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(usrDataSource);
    }

    public JdbcTemplate getUsrJdbcTemplate()
    {
        return this.usrJdbcTemplate;
    }

}
```

The class that extends this, makes use of this JdbcTemplate to query a table:

```
public class OimUserDao extends BaseDao
{
    public Date getPasswordExpiryDate(String userName)
    {

    String sql = "select USR_PWD_EXPIRE_DATE from USR where UPPER (USR_LOGIN) = ?";

    List<java.sql.Date> dtLst  = getUsrJdbcTemplate().query(sql, new Object[] {userName.toUpperCase()}, new RowMapper<java.sql.Date>() 
      {
      @Override
      public java.sql.Date mapRow(final ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException
      {
      return rs.getDate(1);
      }
      });

    if (dtLst.size()>0)
    {
    return dtLst.get(0);
    }
    else
    {
    return null;
    }
    }
}
```

The DAO is autowired in a service using the @Autowired annotation. DAO declarations in the xml:

```
<bean id="baseDao" class="us.worldpay.portalgateway.dao.BaseDao">
    <property name="usrDataSource" ref="usrDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="oimUserDao" class="us.worldpay.portalgateway.dao.OimUserDao" parent="baseDao" />
```

Web.xml has the declaration for the xml containing the bean definitions for these DAO (pg-data is the one we are concerned with):

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/pg-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/pg-data.xml
</param-value>
</context-param>
```

To make things worse, this NEVER happens on my local box (Weblogic) that points to the same database (Oracle) as our QA env does. The result set the first time around is populated and has data when I run this on my local box. When I run this on the QA env (Weblogic), the result set is empty the first time. I have spent hours and hours on this, and have gotten no where.

I appreaciate your time reading this post. I am grateful for all help I can get.

Comment: by 'first time' do you mean the first time the query is run once the webapp is started, or do you mean the first time the query is run for a new user?

Comment: Nathan. Thanks for your response. It is the first time the query is run for a new user. I clear my cache and log into qa again, this is when the code is run again for the "first time", and it fails. When i refresh the page, it goes through.

Comment: sounds like caching could be relevant, could you describe how that's set up?

Comment: I do not have detailed information about that, but we tried this after deleting the cache on weblogic and saw the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for the `BaseDao`.  I'd dispense with it and simply inject the `SimpleJdbcTemplate` into the DAOs that need it.

You should use `PreparedStatement` rather than escaping username on your own.  I wouldn't use a LIKE clause in the query.  Your username should be unique; you should get one Date back.

OK, let's ask some more questions.

You say the ResultSet is empty "the first time".  Are you saying that if you merely re-run the method call that it's not empty?  "I think so, yes."  You need to be certain.  It's central to your question.

Are you sure that your local machine and QA environment are pointing at the very same Oracle instance?  "That I am very sure of.  Yes."  Very good!

If you log onto Oracle with a client and run the identical query, does it bring back the results you expect?  "Yes it does."  Excellent!

Have you stepped through the code with a debugger to see what's happening?  I'd recommend it highly.

One more question: Is there an exception thrown that you're not catching?  Spring wraps SQLException into an unchecked DataAccessException.  Maybe something bad happens the first time that's rectified on the second call.  I'm just grasping at straws here.

Comment: Hello duffymo. Thanks for your response. I was planning on parameterizing the sql later on, but I changed it. As for getting rid of BaseDao, I will be using the JdbcTemplates in other classes also. Besides, I added logging statements to check if my template, data-source and connection were null - but they all seem to be fine. I still get the same error as before.

Comment: I got rid of BaseDao. Still have the same problem.

Comment: Hello again, You say the ResultSet is empty "the first time". Are you saying that if you merely re-run the method call that it's not empty? : I think so yes. At the best its another request from the web, but as far as the backend is concerned, its just another method call.

Are you sure that your local machine and QA environment are pointing at the very same Oracle instance?: That I am very sure of. yes.

If you log onto Oracle with a client and run the identical query, does it bring back the results you expect? Yes it does.

Comment: Hey, about that being just another method call. I am certain now. I tried to force it through a second request (and hence a second method call) and it worked this time around. I will have to remote debug the project as it works fine on my local box and only fails when deployed to qa

Comment: Hi. We deployed this to another qa box and the same thing happens there. About the exception, I have the code in a try catch and log it with a log.error. Before the sql was parameterized, I would get a EmptyResultDataAccessException. But now I don't, I just get no results. I am totally clueless. Thanks for all your help btw.

Comment: I am going to try that next. I have to setup a remote debugger in my eclipse and point to our qa's server I guess. Thanks.

Comment: I'd try it locally first and see what happens there.  You need the good and the bad results.

Comment: locally it works fine the very first go. no issues. and i've tried this on local box with weblogic, tomcat and my unit tests. But I see your point - I'll have a reference to compare to.